# Create an enum class from a list of strings in Python

Tags: python, enums

When I run this

```
from enum import Enum

class MyEnumType(str, Enum):
    RED   = 'RED'
    BLUE  = 'BLUE'
    GREEN = 'GREEN'

for x in MyEnumType:
    print(x)
```

I get the following as expected:

```
MyEnumType.RED
MyEnumType.BLUE
MyEnumType.GREEN
```

Is it possible to create a class like this from a list or tuple that has been obtained from elsewhere?

Something *vaguely similar* to this perhaps:

```
myEnumStrings = ('RED', 'GREEN', 'BLUE')

class MyEnumType(str, Enum):
    def __init__(self):
        for x in myEnumStrings :
            self.setattr(self, x,x)
```

However, in the same way as in the original, I don't want to have to explicitly instantiate an object.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [enum functional API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#functional-api) for this:

```
from enum import Enum


myEnumStrings = ('RED', 'GREEN', 'BLUE')
MyEnumType = Enum('MyEnumType', myEnumStrings)
```

From the docs:

> The first argument of the call to Enum is the name of the enumeration.
>
> The second argument is the source of enumeration member names. It can be a whitespace-separated string of names, a sequence of names, a sequence of 2-tuples with key/value pairs, or a mapping (e.g. dictionary) of names to values.

Comment: nice - thank you.
In addition, in order to get strings for the enum values as in the original, this does the trick: `myEnumStrings = ( (x,x) for x in ('RED', 'GREEN', 'BLUE'))`.

Comment: How do I compare string values with the string enums with the above declaration?
Example:
`'RED'== MyEnumType.RED` @fundamental @will-da-silva

Comment: Figured out. The way to do the comparison `'RED'== MyEnumType.RED`:
`MyEnumType = Enum('MyEnumType', myEnumStrings, type=str)`

Comment: @thegreatcoder You can also use `enum.StrEnum` without the `type` argument instead of `enum.Enum` to achieve this in Python 3.11+